# PHP MySQL: COUNT/SUM a non integer column with different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-by

My table looks like this:

```
ID | click |    time    | browser

1      1      [01:00:00]     FireFox
2      1      [01:00:00]     FireFox
3      0      [01:00:00]     Opera
4      1      [02:00:00]     FireFox
5      1      [02:00:00]     Chrome
6      1      [02:00:00]     Chrome
```

So output should be:

```
01:00:00
Total hits: 3
Clicks: 2
FireFox: 2
Opera: 1

02:00:00
Total hits: 3
Clicks: 3
FireFox: 1
Chrome: 2
```

I know how to get this without Browser:

```
SELECT SUM(click) AS click, COUNT(*), HOUR(time) 
FROM hits 
WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY HOUR(time)
```

But I don't know to ouput this with browser.
I wouldn't mind at all if browser would not be grouped and I get a output like this:

```
01:00:00
Total hits: 3
Clicks: 2

02:00:00
Total hits: 3
Clicks: 3
-----------

FireFox: 3
Chrome: 2
Opera: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` :

```
SELECT SUM(`click`) AS click
     , COUNT(*)
     , HOUR(`time`)
     , COUNT(IF( `browser` = 'Chrome', `browser`, null)) AS `Chrome`
     , COUNT(IF( `browser` = 'Opera', `browser`, null)) AS `Opera`
     , COUNT(IF( `browser` = 'FireFox', `browser`, null)) AS 'FireFox'
FROM `hits` 
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY HOUR(`time`)
```

or `CASE` :

```
SELECT SUM(`click`) AS click
     , COUNT(*)
     , HOUR(`time`)
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `browser` = 'Chrome' THEN `browser` END) AS `Chrome`
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `browser` = 'Opera' THEN `browser` END) AS `Opera`
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN `browser` = 'FireFox' THEN `browser` END) AS 'FireFox'
FROM `hits` 
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY HOUR(`time`)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! But I have another question. I have this same situation with Countries. So instead of Browsers I want to count how many visits are from a certain country. In the country column I save country codes. But if I use case or if like your answer I will have an enormous query.

Comment: So is a query like this possible: `COUNT(country_code) AS country_code`

Comment: @yoshi : No, unfortunately, it is not possible without using multiple `CASE` or `IF` in MySQL.

Comment: So I should not use `GROP BY` instead do something in a foreach (entry) loop?

Comment: @yoshi : Well, now I am a bit stuck with your question, but yeah, you can do it using multiple queries in generated in foreach.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. What I meant is that I don't use `GROUP BY`. I `fetchAll` entries which I want into an array. This array I loop with `foreach`. Here I "group" by myself the entries by HOUR with some code "manually" but now I can "manually" count Browser and Countries more easily. Or am I wrong? Is this worse for performance?

Comment: @yoshi : You can fetch separately `HOUR` and `Browser`, after that in the loop you can build query dynamically to fetch result for each hour including each browser.(two nested `foreach` loops). Anyway it is a long story so you better try it yourself and if you have problems post a new question with code in php (I guess) and related queries.

Comment: Why use `count()` at all?  It is much cleaner just to say `sum(`browser` = 'Chrome')` and so on.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not sure how that does work. So for example `SUM(browser = 'Chrome') AS chrome, SUM(browser = 'Firefox') AS firefox,... ` will save save the SUM of all fields where value is "Chome" as chrome? Thanks.

Comment: The boolean is treated as an integer with a value of 1 for true and 0 for false.  So the `sum()` will count the number of matches.